# Merging data by 2 variables in R

Tags: r, merge

I am attempting to merge two data sets. In the past I have used `merge()` with `by` equal to the variable I want to merge by. However, now I would like to do so with two variables. My first data set looks something like this:

```
Year   Winning_Tm    Losing_Tm
2011   Texas         Washington
2012   Alabama       South Carolina
2013   Tennessee     Texas
```

Then I have another data set with a rank of each team (this is very simplified) for each year. Like this:

```
Year    Team             Rank
2011    Texas            32
2011    Washington       34
2012    South Carolina   45
2012    Alabama          12
2013    Texas            6
2013    Tennessee        51
```

I would like to merge them so I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Year   Winning_Tm    Winning_TM_rank    Losing_Tm        Losing_Tm_rank
2011   Texas         32                 Washington       34
2012   Alabama       12                 South Carolina   45
2013   Tennessee     51                 Texas            6
```

My hope is that there is a simple way to do this but it may be more complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two separate merges. You would need to wrap your list of `by` variables in `c()`, and since the variables have different names, you need `by.x` and `by.y`. Afterward you could rename the rank variables.

I'll call your data `winlose` and `teamrank`, respectively. Then you'd need:

```
first_merge <- merge(winlose, teamrank, by.x = c('Year', 'Winning_Tm'), by.y = c('Year', 'Team'))
second_merge <- merge(first_merge, teamrank, by.x = c('Year', 'Losing_Tm'), by.y = c('Year', 'Team'))
```

Renaming the variables:

```
names(second_merge)[names(second_merge) == 'Rank.x'] <- 'Winning_Tm_rank'
names(second_merge)[names(second_merge) == 'Rank.y'] <- 'Losing_Tm_rank'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `rank` is a built-in function, which may result in unwanted name collisions.

Comment: Ah, good catch, I never had used that function. Edited my answer to change `rank` to `teamrank`.

Answer (score 4):

I reproduced your data (try to include a `dput` of it next time):

```
A <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2011, 2012, 2013),
  Winning_Tm = c("Texas","Alabama","Tennessee"),
  Losing_Tm = c("Washington","South Carolina", "Texas"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

B <- data.frame(
  Year = c("2011","2011","2012","2012","2013","2013"),
  Team = c("Texas","Washington","South Carolina","Alabama","Texas","Tennessee"),
  Rank = c(32,34,45,12,6,51),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

You can `melt` the first dataframe using the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)

A <- melt(A, id.vars = "Year")
names(A)[3] <- "Team"
```

Now it looks like this:

```
> A
  Year   variable           Team
1 2011 Winning_Tm          Texas
2 2012 Winning_Tm        Alabama
3 2013 Winning_Tm      Tennessee
4 2011  Losing_Tm     Washington
5 2012  Losing_Tm South Carolina
6 2013  Losing_Tm          Texas
```

You can then merge the datasets together by the two columns of interest:

```
AB <- merge(A, B, by=c("Year","Team"))
```

Which looks like this:

```
> AB
  Year           Team   variable Rank
1 2011          Texas Winning_Tm   32
2 2011     Washington  Losing_Tm   34
3 2012        Alabama Winning_Tm   12
4 2012 South Carolina  Losing_Tm   45
5 2013      Tennessee Winning_Tm   51
6 2013          Texas  Losing_Tm    6
```

Then using the `reshape` command from base R you can change `AB` to a wide format:

```
reshape(AB, idvar = "Year", timevar = "variable", direction = "wide")
```

The result:

```
  Year Team.Winning_Tm Rank.Winning_Tm Team.Losing_Tm Rank.Losing_Tm
1 2011           Texas              32     Washington             34
3 2012         Alabama              12 South Carolina             45
5 2013       Tennessee              51          Texas              6
```

Comment: I have used your method and it works well, except that it appears to be confusing teams that repeat (I think). here is the warning message: Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for variable=L_Tm: first taken
2: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for variable=W_Tm: first taken

Comment: Good point @a.powell. Does the resulting dataframe after `reshape` only show the repeated teams once?

Comment: It only showed games from "Air Force" the first alphabetical team in the list. And reshaped them playing themselves.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with `SQL` a rather complicated, but fast way to do this all in one step would be:

```
res <- sqldf("SELECT l.*,
                     max(case when l.Winning_Tm = r.Team then r.Rank else 0 end) as Winning_Tm_rank,
                     max(case when l.Losing_Tm = r.Team then r.Rank else 0 end) as Losing_Tm_rank
             FROM      df1 as l
             inner join df2 as r
             on        (l.Winning_Tm = r.Team
             OR        l.Losing_Tm = r.Team)
             AND       l.Year = r.Year
             group by  l.Year, l.Winning_Tm, l.Losing_Tm")

res
  Year Winning_Tm      Losing_Tm Winning_Tm_rank Losing_Tm_rank
1 2011      Texas     Washington              32             34
2 2012    Alabama South_Carolina              12             45
3 2013  Tennessee          Texas              51              6
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T,text="Year   Winning_Tm    Losing_Tm
2011   Texas         Washington
2012   Alabama       South_Carolina
2013   Tennessee     Texas")

df2<- read.table(header=T,text="Year Team Rank
2011    Texas            32
2011    Washington       34
2012    South_Carolina   45
2012    Alabama          12
2013    Texas            6
2013    Tennessee        51")
```